# How to change tabs programmatically in jquery-ui 1.9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

How do you change tabs programmatically with jquery-ui 1.9?

**NOTE:** Posting the answer because it took me more than 4 searches to find the right answer on stackoverflow.  It appears in 1.9 the API has changed, in earlier versions, you would use `$("#tabs").tabs("select", 2)`.

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#tabs").tabs();

      // assume you want to change to the 3rd tab after 3 seconds
      setTimeout(function() {
         // ???
      }, 3000);
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1"><p>Container 1</p></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"><p>Container 2</p></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"><p>Container 3</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `select` method is [deprecated since 1.9](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#removed-select-method-use-active-option), and was [removed in 1.10](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#removed-select-method-use-active-option). Use the `active` option instead.

Example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V8S5G/2/) also provided):

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#tabs").tabs();

      // assume you want to change to the 3rd tab after 3 seconds
      setTimeout(function() {
          $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 2);
      }, 3000);
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1"><p>Container 1</p></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"><p>Container 2</p></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"><p>Container 3</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesn't work in jquey UI 1.11, had to trigger a click event on the anchor element.

Answer (score 8):

Selection according id is very straight forward as [Sonjz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15304028/1334561) specified above ... but selection according to tabId is trickier .. I just want to share it in case anybody needs

```
var index = $('#tabs a[href="#tab_id"]').parent().index();
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", index);
```

Comment: I got it working by doing `$('#tabs a[href="#tab_id"]')[0].click();`

Comment: This solution will work even if you insert new tabs before the target tab, whereas the accepted answer will break.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
$('#tabs a[href="#tabs-2"]').tab('show')
```

Here `#tabs-2` means the tab you want to switch.

Comment: I know I'm repeating myself but this solution will work even if you insert new tabs before the target tab, whereas the accepted answer will break.

Answer (score 1):

If you add an id to the tab list elements, you can simulate a click using jQuery click() method.

For example the following will activate tab2 when clicking the button outside of the tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1" id="th1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2" id="th2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3" id="th3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1"><p>Container 1</p></div>
  <div id="tabs-2"><p>Container 2</p></div>
  <div id="tabs-3"><p>Container 3</p></div>
</div>
<button id="btn">Click to activate Tab 2</button>
<script>
$("#tabs").tabs();
$('#btn').click(function() {$('#th2').click()});
</script>
```