# Select tab using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used jquery tab into my UI. what I need to do is, I need to select the second tab when the page gets loaded. By default it is opening the tag with class="Active". But rather than opening the contents of Active tag I want to open content of another tag. How do i do this.  Here is my tab code in html:

```
<div class="typo">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="Buttons">
            <!--  <h3 class="ghj"><p align="center">Modules</p></h3>-->
             <h1>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Basic" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Data Preprocessing</a></li>
                  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#WGCNA" class="btn btn-info" role="button">WGCNA</a></li>
                  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Custom" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Genome Mapping</a></li>
                  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#RNA" class="btn btn-info" role="button">RNA Seq</a></li>
                  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                </ul>
             </h1>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here what i need to do is, I need to display the content of tab 'WGCNA' on page load. How do i achieve this?

Comment: did you tried setting active to the second tab?

Comment: Yes i tried setting Active to second using addClass method of jquery but after doing this I am getting blank page and the WGCNA tab is not getting Active neither do I get the content of it.

Comment: check the SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304027/how-to-change-tabs-programmatically-in-jquery-ui-1-9

Comment: in case you need to swtich tab to `active` on page load, then set class directly in `html` code, without jquery

Comment: You could at least trigger a click on the other tab to open it on page load :D http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically open tabs using the [tabs api](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/).

There are two ways to achieve this.

You can do at the initialization passing the `active` option on start like this:

```
$( ".nav-tabs" ).tabs({
 active: 1
});
```

Remember it's zero-based.

Or setting the active option after the initialization:

```
$( ".nav-tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
```