# How to load newly created (dynamic) jquery tab after tabs refresh?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a js function that adds an extra tab + panel to an existing JQuery UI [tab widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/) upon the click of a button,

```
let $tabs = $('#my-tab').tabs(options);

$button.click(function(e){
  let $newtab = $('#additional-tab'),
    $newpanle = $('#additional-panel'),
    ref = '#'+$newpanel.attr('id');

  $tabs.children('ul').append($newtab);
  $tabs.append($newpanel);
  
  //I would now like to load the newly created tab.
  $tabs.on('tabscreate', function(e,ui){
    $tabs.tabs("load",ref);
  });
  //refresh to enable the new tab/panel.
  $tabs.tabs("refresh");
})
```

The new tab/panel get created, but I wish to load it once the widget is "refresh"ed.  I have tried to bind to all the events a tabs widget fires,

```
$tabs.on('tabsbeforeactivate,tabsbeforeload, tabscreate, tabsload, tabsactivate', function(e,ui){
   $tabs.tabs("load",ref);
 });
```

but none of them are fired by the widget when it is refreshed.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you need to trigger a `click` event on the new tab to load it.

Comment: thanks for the help, the tabs("load",ref) is the documented method to so this, my trouble is executing this after the tabs are refreshed.

Comment: @Twisty you're right, only way to get it to open the tab is to trigger a click event, even [changing the active option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15304028/3596672) doesn't work.  Executing a delay(200) prior to the event trigger ensure the tabs are properly refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

So after much experiment, I finally reverted to the following solution,

```
$button.click(function(e){
  let $newtab = $('#additional-tab'),
    $newpanle = $('#additional-panel'),
    ref = '#'+$newpanel.attr('id');

  $tabs.children('ul').append($newtab);
  $tabs.append($newpanel);
  
  //refresh to enable the new tab/panel.
  $tabs.tabs("refresh");

  //activate the new tab,
  $('a', $newtab).delay(200).click();
})
```

the `delay(200)` ensures the tabs("refresh") has got time to complete.

Another possible solution is to destroy and recreate the tabs with the active option set to the new tab,

```
$button.click(function(e){
  let $newtab = $('#additional-tab'),
    $newpanle = $('#additional-panel'),
    ref = '#'+$newpanel.attr('id');

  $tabs.children('ul').append($newtab);
  $tabs.append($newpanel);
  
  //refresh to enable the new tab/panel.
  let idx = $tabs.children('ul').children('li').length-1;

  $tabs.tabs("destroy").tabs({active:idx});
})
```